error connecting the sms database using the npm tedious package
Please help me, I've been suffering for several hours, but I can't connect to the database in SQL Server Management Studio 20. I have already configured SQL and enabled TCP IP, but it still does not work.
const { Connection, Request } = require("tedious");

// Настройки подключения к базе данных
const config = {
  authentication: {
    options: {
      userName: "server",
      password: "12345678",
    },
    type: "default",
  },
  server: "WIN-BOEG8IKMEF7",
  options: {
    instanceName: "SQLEXPRESS",
    database: "Zaivki",
    rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: true,
  },
};

// Создание подключения
const connection = new Connection(config);

// Обработка событий подключения
connection.on("connect", (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Ошибка подключения: ", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Подключение успешно!");
    executeSQL();
  }
});

Error stacktrace:
Ошибка подключения:  ConnectionError: Failed to connect to WIN-BOEG8IKMEF7\SQLEXPRESS in 15000ms
    at Connection.connectTimeout (F:\zaivka\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1222:26)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (F:\zaivka\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1167:12)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:581:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
  code: 'ETIMEOUT'
}

Configuration in SQL Server Management Studio:



This is not related to the ANSI SQL language, so I removed the  tag. Add a tag for the dbms instead.
